# How to use returned value from a function

Tags: python, function, return

I have a function that finds all paths through a graph. The function returns a list of all paths. How do I use this value later in my code?

```
def findpaths(attachednodes,startID,endID,path = []):
    path = path + [startID]

    if startID == endID:
        return [path]

    if startID not in attachednodes:
        return []

    paths = []
    for n in attachednodes[startID]:
        if n not in path:
            newpath = findpaths(attachednodes,n,endID,path)
            for new in newpath:
                paths.append(new)

    for i in range(len(paths)):
        numflight = i
        flight = paths[i]
        flights.update({numflight: flight})

    return paths
```

Comment: What do you mean by sayin using the value later in your code?

Comment: Just call the function? `my_path = findpaths(nodes, start, end)`

Comment: Note, that a mutable object as your empty list is a bad default value. Compare [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) under *Mutable Default Arguments*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you put the function call to the right side of a variable assignment. The variable will have the return value:
e.g.

```
def some_function():
  return 10

x = some_function()
print(x) # will print 10
```